# is there any way to stop a (c = getchar()) != EOF) if my work inside the while loop is done?

Tags: c, eof

I am reading the C programming language book Dennis M. Ritchie and
trying to solve this question:

> Write a program to print a histogram of
> the lengths of words in
> its input. It is easy to draw the histogram with the bars horizontal; a vertical
> orientation is more challenging.

I think my solution works, but the problem is that if I don't press EOF, the terminal won't show the
result. I know that the condition specifies that exactly, but I am
wondering whether there is any way to make the program terminate after
reading a single line? (Sorry if my explanation of the problem is a bit shallow. Feel free to ask more.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int digits[10];
  int nc=0;
  int c, i, j;
  for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    digits[i] = 0;
  //take input;
  while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF) {
      ++nc;
      if (c == ' ' || c=='\n') {
          ++digits[nc-1];
          //is it also counting the space in nc? i think it is,so we should do nc-1
          nc = 0;
       }
   }
   for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        printf("%d :", i);
        for (j = 1; j <= digits[i]; j++) {
            printf ("*");
        }
        printf ("\n");
   }  
   // I think this is a problem with getchar()
   //the program doesn't exit automatically
   //need to find a way to do it
}
```

Comment: `c == ' ' || c=='\n'` you are already treating `\n` as separator, maybe you need to define some special character as terminator and update the `while` loop as `while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF && c != $special_char$)`

Comment: It's not "a problem with getchar()".  It's simply the way it works - if you're reading from the console, you need to explicitly "terminate" console input (e.g. with a Ctl-D in a DOS prompt).  Of course, you can use ANY character you want to signal "end of user input".  For example, you could say `while ((c = getchar ()) != '$') {...}`, at which point your loop will terminate if you type in "$: ;)  The ENTER key (`\n`) is commonly used like this.

Comment: You can fake EOF at a command prompt with `Ctrl-D` in Unix and `Ctrl-Z` in Windows.  If you redirect the input from a file it automatically has an end of file marker.  What I would do if you want the program to exit without that EOF maybe you could check for an empty line and exit when you see that instead.

Comment: Also review `int digits[10]; ... for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) ...`  Why iterate 11 times?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica my bad, it should be `i<=9?` right? considering the declared array only has 10 indexes.  I think if i write `for(i=1;.....i<=10)` that will be fine too, am i right?

Comment: @NajmusSakib No.  For `int digits[10];`, use `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thanks, i understand it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make something like

```
while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
```

and then adding a line after the while loop to account for the last word:

```
if (c == '\n') {
      ++digits[nc-1];
      nc = 0;
```

There is also another problem inside your program. `++digits[nc-1];` is correct, however, for the wrong reason. You should make it because an array starts at zero, i.e. if you have an array of length 10, it will go from 0 to 9, so you should count the length of the words and then add one to the position of the array `length - 1` (as there are no words of length zero). The problem is that you are still counting the blank spaces or the newline characters inside the length of a word, so if you have two blank spaces after a word of length 4, the program will add to the array a word of length 5 + a word of length 1. To avoid this, you should do something like this:

```
while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF) {
      if ((c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') && nc > 0) {
          ++digits[nc-1]; // arrays start at zero
          nc = 0;
      }
      else {
          ++nc;
      }
}
```

Comment: `'/n'` -> `'\n'`.